# How to Update Existing PostgreSQL using PGAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

So I want to be able to update my PostgreSQL that I use as a DataAdpater in jaspersoftstudio. I am having trouble connecting to PostgreSQL using PGAdmin, I am completely new to this and any direction of help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I add this server as a connection on PGadmin?

Comment: What error are you encountering? If you haven't encountered any error, if means you aren't trying hard enough. If you have, please search the error in Google. Usually, you'll find the answer. Only when you've googled and found nothing, then you can come back to SO for help.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I was having problems connecting before. I just needed some clarification with the host-name.

Comment: I can not insert new values into my rows, in my existing database

Answer (score 0):

Create a new connection

[image]

Fill the connection parameters

[image]

Comment: thank you for the reply, I am having trouble connecting my server. I am using JasperDB and Password. Where can I find the information detailing what is needed for the connection to work.

Comment: well, depend is your db local or remote, do you have user/password?

Comment: It is a localhost DB, yes I do have a user/password.

Comment: Then what is the problem?

Comment: How Can I locate my Host name/address, port, Do I keep Maintenace DB as postgres. And Input Jasperdb and password  under username/password?. I get a error when I try to connect , saying unable to connect.

Comment: Name: is anything you want. Host: `localhost`, Port is `5432` unless you change it during installation. MaintenaceDB  is `postgres`, username/password you should have it, dont need anything else.